# Python C package source code header files are missing

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, cpython, python-c-extension

I am working on modifying source code for python C extension module ceODBC.

I set up the C source code of ceODBC in Visual studio as a C++ project and linked python source code (so including Python.h in ceODBC won't cause any issue).

However, there is no linkage between C scripts within ceODBC source code since I didn't see any header file(.h) in ceODBC package. How should I link those C scripts?

Comment: You should never use a C++ compiler for C code.

Comment: I followed steps in this post to complie C code in Visual studio on windows machine @Olaf [link](http://www.zealfortechnology.com/2013/06/compile-c-program-using-visual-studio-2012.html)

Comment: "I set up the C source code of ceODBC in Visual studio as a C++ project". Does not sound like you actually did.